# Differences between different flavours of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr, tr1

Are there any differences between [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and the upcoming (in `C++0x`) `std::shared_ptr`?

Will porting from one to another have any overhead or are they basically the same?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but c++0x's unique_ptr will be an improvement on scoped_ptr where you can do things like this: std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the Boost website, the `boost::shared_ptr`...

> ...conforms to the TR1 specification, with the only exception that it resides in namespace `boost` instead of `std::tr1`.

According to the Wikipedia [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) page

> The TR1 implementation lacked certain pointer features such as aliasing and pointer arithmetic, but the C++0x version will add these.

If your code works with the TR1/Boost version, it should work with the C++0x version (but not necessarily vice versa).