# C++0x Error: overloading a function with std::shared_ptr to const argument is ambiguous

Tags: c++, boost, stl, overloading, shared-ptr

Suppose I have two **unrelated** classes `A` and `B`. I also have a class `Bla` that uses `boost::shared_ptr` like this:

```
class Bla {
public:
    void foo(boost::shared_ptr<const A>);
    void foo(boost::shared_ptr<const B>);
}
```

Notice the **const**. That's the important part which the original version of this question lacked. This compiles, and the following code works:

```
Bla bla;
boost::shared_ptr<A> a;
bla.foo(a);
```

However, if I switch from using `boost::shared_ptr` to using `std::shared_ptr` in the above examples, I get a compilation error that says:

```
"error: call of overloaded 'foo(std::shared_ptr<A>)' is ambiguous
note: candidates are: void foo(std::shared_ptr<const A>)
                      void foo(std::shared_ptr<const B>)
```

Can you help me figure out why the compiler can't figure out which function to use in the std::shared_ptr case, and can in the boost::shared_ptr case? I'm using the default GCC and Boost versions from the Ubuntu 11.04 package repository which are currently GCC 4.5.2 and Boost 1.42.0.

Here is the full code that you can try compiling:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using boost::shared_ptr;
// #include <memory>
// using std::shared_ptr;

class A {};
class B {};

class Bla {
public:
    void foo(shared_ptr<const A>) {}
    void foo(shared_ptr<const B>) {}
};

int main() {
    Bla bla;
    shared_ptr<A> a;

    bla.foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, this issue motivated me to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322245/should-i-switch-from-using-boostshared-ptr-to-stdshared-ptr) about whether I should be using `std::shared_ptr` at all yet ;-)

Comment: What compiler (version)?

Comment: Perhaps you include more code and #include paths etc?

Comment: The original question was incorrect in that it was missing a "const" in the template type of the shared_ptr. I fixed that and provided the full code example.

Comment: Which version of Boost are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default GCC and Boost versions from the Ubuntu 11.04 package repository which are currently GCC 4.5.2 and Boost 1.42.0.

Comment: @Lex I can reproduce the problem. It's not present when switching to a more recent GCC though. Perhaps you might want to test out gcc-snapshot, or manually install GCC 4.6 proper.

Comment: @Luc, great to hear. Thank you for providing a light at the end of the tunnel ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shared_ptr` has a template single-argument constructor, which is considered for the conversion here.  That's what allows an actual parameter `shared_ptr<Derived>` to be supplied where a `shared_ptr<Base>` is needed.

Since both `shared_ptr<const A>` and `shared_ptr<const B>` have this implicit conversion, it's ambiguous.

At least in C++0x, the standard requires that `shared_ptr` use some SFINAE tricks to make sure that the template constructor only matches types that actually can be converted.

The signature is (see section `[util.smartptr.shared.const]`):

```
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
```

> Requires: The second constructor shall not participate in the overload resolution unless `Y*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`.

Possibly the library hasn't yet been updated to comply with that requirement.  You might try a newer version of libc++.

Boost won't work, because it's missing that requirement.

Here's a simpler test case: http://ideone.com/v4boA  (This test case will fail on a conforming compiler, if it compiles successfully, it means the original case will be incorrectly reported as ambiguous.)

VC++ 2010 gets it right (for `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Normally, `shared_ptr`'s constructor has such an SFINAE construct with `std::is_convertible`. Unrelated classes shouldn't be convertible.

Comment: @Xeo: The standard requires that EXACT signature.  There's no SFINAE going on.  Or have I missed something?  Ok, yeah I've missed something.  That signature isn't a converting constructor, it has two arguments.  It's the next one down that's important.

Comment: @Ben: I should also read the edited answer, not just your comment. :P I've skimmed through the standard to find the relevant part, but you already did that. +1

Comment: @Xeo: `std::shared_ptr` is new in C++0x, isn't it?  So there's no need to consider the C++03 wording.  And Boost does NOT have the implicitly convertible requirement.

Comment: @Ben: Meh, C++0x should become the standard already, as I'm already referring to it as such... meant the FDIS of course.

Comment: @Xeo: I tend to call C++0x "a" standard.  C++03 is also "a" standard.  Which one I use for "the" standard when talking about compiler bugs depends on the compiler version (i.e. its unreasonable to say a three-year old compiler has a bug if it doesn't implement C++0x changes).

Comment: @Ben, sorry, but could you clarify if passing a `shared_ptr<A>` to a `foo(shared_ptr<const A>)` function is incorrect behavior, and requires a conversion like the one @Jon provides. The simpler test case is actually mixing A and B so it's a little different.

Comment: @Lex: Sorry, just added an explanation to the test case.  Your code should work with `std::shared_ptr` according to the C++ specification, it will not work with `boost::shared_ptr`.  Unfortunately the version of g++ (or libc++) you are using doesn't correct implement the specification.  I don't know if it's fixed in a newer version.

Answer (score 6):

The following compiles fine with GCC 4.5 and Visual Studio 10. If you say it doesn't compile in GCC 4.5.2 then it sounds like a compiler bug which you should report (but make sure that it really happens it's more likely that you made some sort of typo).

```
#include <memory>
class A{};
class B{};
class Bla {
public:
    void foo(std::shared_ptr<A>) {}
    void foo(std::shared_ptr<B>) {}
};

int main()
{
    Bla bla;
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    bla.foo(a);
}
```

Comment: It also compiles fine with Visual C++ 2010 SP1.

Comment: I can confirm this with GCC 4.5 as well.

Comment: Thank you guys. This answers the original question which had `shared_ptr<A>` and not `shared_ptr<const A>` as it should have. It does indeed compile with both `boost::` and `std::` versions. The problem comes in when the const is added as the modified question now explains.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::static_pointer_cast` to add the `const` qualification:

```
bla.foo(std::static_pointer_cast<const A>(a));
```

Comment: There *is* an automatic conversion. See @Ben's answer.

Comment: @Xeo: Removed that assertion to leave only the solution (or workaround, if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/832994-shared_ptr-derived-classes-ambiguitity-overloaded-functions

```
struct yes_type { char dummy; };
struct no_type { yes_type a; yes_type b; };

template < typename From, typename To >
class is_convertible
{
    private:
        static From* dummy ( void );

        static yes_type check ( To );

        static no_type check ( ... );

    public:

        static bool const value = sizeof( check( *dummy() ) ) == sizeof( yes_type );

}; // is_convertible
```

An in boost's shared_ptr.h, change the constructor signature to:

```
template<class Y>
shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r,
    typename enable_if<is_convertible<Y*, T*>::value, void*>::type = 0
    ): px(r.px), pn(r.pn) // never throws
{
}
```