# Side effects of enabling C++0x support in gcc

Tags: gcc, c++11

Following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322245/should-i-switch-from-using-boostshared-ptr-to-stdshared-ptr), I'm wondering if there're some side effects of enabling C++0x in GCC.

According to [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html): "GCC's support for C++0x is **experimental**".

What I'm afraid of is that for example compiler will generate some code differently or standard library uses some C++0x feature which is broken in gcc.

So if I don't explicitly use any of C++0x features, may it break my existing code?

Comment: The "experimental" part is that the implementation started before the standard was finalized. That means that some parts actually changed as the draft standard evolved. If you define broken as "the way the draft standard looked when the compiler was released", then some things might be broken now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++0x support has been, and is under heavy development. One thing this means is that bugs get fixed quickly, another thing it means is that there might be small bugs present. I say small, because of two reasons:

1. `libstdc++` has not been rewritten from scratch, so all the old elements are just as stable as it was before any of this `c++0x` was available, if not more stable, because of several years of bug fixes.
2. There's corner cases in the new/old Standard that haven't yet been ironed out. Are these the runtime quirks you talk about? No. `C++0x` support has been under development for 4 releases now, don't worry.

Most of the impact from that flag will be felt in the new *language* features, the library features like move constructors and `std::thread` (on posix platforms) don't affect code not using them.

Bottom line, *experimental* is too strict a word in daily production. The standard has changed in the three/four years GCC has been working on support. Old revisions of `c++0x` will be broken in a newer GCC, but that's a good thing. `C++0x` is finished as far as the non-paying-for-a-pdf-world is concerned, so no breaking changes should be added. Decide if you want the new stuff or not beforehand, because you won't be able to jsut switch it off once you've gotten used to using it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it won't break your source code, but you may include (even without noticing it or knowing it) C++0x idioms that will compile because of these features enabled, but won't compile in a strict C++ compiler (for instance, in C++0x you can use `>>` as a template of template terminator, but not in C++, so if you forget to separate it by a space, you will have problems when you try to compile this code in a C++ compiler).

Comment: I'm more concerned about run time quirks.

Comment: @dimba: Yes, new features may include also bug in the generated code, even for other parts that don't have to do with C++0x (and even if you don't enable the support). In other cases, those bugs will only be present if you enable the C++0x support. At this point, I don't think anybody would know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[R-Value references/moves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Rvalue_reference_and_move_semantics) is a feature which can have a huge impact on how the compiler does optimizations and such.  Even if you don't use move in your own code, the STD includes will automatically switch to their new versions which include move ctors/assignment.

There are some circumstances which allow the compiler to create move constructors/assignment operators implicitly for user defined classes.  These rules changed a few times during the standardization process (I don't even know what the current rules are).  So, depending on the exact version of your compiler it could be using a set of rules for generating these implicit functions that isn't even in the latest version of the standard.

Most of the other major C++0x changes don't have big run-time impact, they are mostly compile time (constexpr, string literals, varadic templates) or syntax helpers (foreach, auto, initializer lists).

Comment: I should mention that the standard's rules fro compiler-generated implicit move ctor/assignment was designed careful *not* to break existing code.  But these could be some corner cases. (I can't find a quick reference for what the final wording was on implicit move...)

Answer (score 1):

I originally wrote the question you link because of (in my opinion) a very big issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6322364/627517). Basically, overloading a function with `shared_ptr` to a `const` type was not recognized by the compiler. That's a huge flaw in my opinion. It's been fixed from GCC 4.5 to GCC 4.6, but it serves as an example of a big bug that's still around in the default installation of GCC in ubuntu, for example. So while bugs are fixed quickly, there still might be bugs, and you may waste a weekend looking for the source and solution of those bugs.

My recommendation, based on this personal experience, is to avoid C++0x until the word "experimental" is removed from the description of GCC's support of C++0x or until you actually need any of the C++0x features to a degree that an alternative implementation would significantly sacrifice good design.

Comment: +1 When reading your question I thought thqt you was interesting to know the answer to question I was asking and not only regarding threads.