# Does C++11 have wrappers for dynamically-allocated arrays like Boost's scoped_array?

Tags: c++11, memory-management, boost, wrapper, smart-pointers

I often need to deal with dynamically-allocated arrays in C++, and hence rely on Boost for scoped_array, shared_array, and the like. After reading through [Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) and the [C++11 Reference Wiki](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), I could not find a suitable replacement for these dynamic array wrappers that is provided by the C++11 standard. Is there something that I have overlooked, or do I have to continue relying on Boost?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a specialization of `unique_ptr`, like `unique_ptr<T[]>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct test
{
  ~test() { std::cout << "test::dtor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<test[]> array(new test[3]);
}
```

When you run it, you will get this messages.

```
test::dtor
test::dtor
test::dtor
```

---

If you want to use `shared_ptr`, you should use `std::default_delete<T[]>` for deleter since it doesn't have one like `shared_ptr<t[]>`.

```
std::shared_ptr<test> array(new test[3], std::default_delete<test[]>());
```

Comment: That specialization also provides `T& operator[](size_t)` to access the members.

Answer (score 0):

So far as vectors are intended as array wrappers, what if you use any suitable smart pointer with the vector as inner object?

Comment: vector::emplace_back() and vector::push_back() won't work if the element type is not copy-constructible. I don't know about initializing with an initializer list, but i suspect that has the same problem.

Comment: Yep, you're right, in that case we need to wrap such non-copyable things with extra wrapper, that tends to be some overkill indeed :)