# Mapping memory of one vector to another

Tags: c++, vector, mapping

I have a vector of binary data used by some middleware

`std::vector<uint> data`

The data inside this vector maps to a class `Foo` basically like that:

```
|uint|uint|uint|uint|uint|uint|uint|uint|uint|
|    F o o     |    F o o     |    F o o     |
```

Using a custom placement allocator (as described here [Can I use an std::vector as a facade for a pre-allocated (raw) array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807192/can-i-use-an-stdvector-as-a-facade-for-a-pre-allocated-raw-array)) I can now map the memory of the first vector to a vector of type `std::vector<Foo>`

But if I operate on the second vector the size of the first one is not updated.

Another approach would be to encapsulate the first vector `std::vector<uint8>` in a custom container which behaves like a `std::vector<Foo>` but this is a lot of effort (and I cannot use Boost).

Any ideas for an elegant solution?

Comment: *'But if I operate on the second vector the size of the first one is not updated.'* - not only - if you need to re-allocate because of new elements, other vector won't get updated as well (instead, the link between both gets entirely lost). I assume the middleware is not under your control, is it?

Comment: Yes, as @Aconcagua says, define 'operate on'.  What changes to that vector do you need to make?  Or, to take a more holistic view, what does a `std::vector` give you that makes you want to jump through these hoops in order to use it?

Comment: What operations do you need to do on `vector<Foo>`? I'd do something simple like `auto start = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(vec.data()); auto finish = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(vec.data() + vec.size());` Then use `start` to `finish` as a range. Write utility functions for things like `push_back`.

Comment: @Filipp That's more or less the custom container already mentioned... But actually, it appears to me the most *'elegant'* solution anyway, even if there's quite some effort...

Comment: @Aconcagua: What I would do to prevent the reallocation is to provide a custom allocator which keeps the memory mapping consistent (see the link). Still the sizes are not synchronized.

Comment: So you want to be able to remove elements only - or at least never add more elements that initially have been in?

Comment: @Aconcagua: I can live with the requirement that the capacity of the first vector is fixed. But the allocator could have a reference to the first vector and deduce the maximum size this way. So I have full control over the allocator. But on an allocator level I do not know about the size of the vector using it only about its capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is very different to the linked question. You aren't dealing with preallocated storage, you have data for objects already there. Furthermore, you wish to have *both* sides be able to modify the vector, or in other words they have shared ownership.

This isn't trivial. You can provide a "view class" that offers another set of operations on the same vector or have a family of free functions do the same. Either way they must have reference semantics.

A free function example

```
template<typename T>
void push_back_foo(std::vector<uint8_t>& vec, T&& t)
{
    auto it = vec.insert(vec.end(), sizeof(Foo), {});
    new (&*it) Foo{std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

And so on for all the other functions. They map operations on the `Foo` side to operations on the `uint8_t` side.

A side note: doing pointer arithmetic on the resulting vector is formally undefined behaviour because there is no array of `Foo` there. When dealing with overlaying binary data with a facade, it is generally understood that compilers won't burn down your house and such formalities are ignored.