# C++ Initialization array handled by boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In my class I would like to have some dynamically allocated boolean array. I use `shared_ptr` to hold it:

```
boost::shared_ptr<bool[]> someBoolArray;
```

Memory allocation occurs in class constructor:

```
// someValue was read from file
someBoolArray = boost::shared_ptr<bool[]>(new bool[someValue]);
```

Is it possible to set initial value for my array during shared_ptr initialization?
I want all values in array to be false by default.

Comment: Is zero-initialization ok, or does it have to be a specific, user-defined set of values?

Comment: I want all values in array to be false by default.

Comment: You should use `boost::shared_array` for this.

Comment: shared_ptr does not work that way, see e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624146/c11-standard-scoped-array-wrappers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to guarantee the elements are set to `false`, you need an expression of the type

```
new T[N]();
```

In this case,

```
someBoolArray = boost::shared_ptr<bool[]>(new bool[someValue]()); 
//                                                           ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

in C++11 you can pass initializer to array:

```
new bool[someValue] {false}
```

And I suggest you to use make_shared instead of your form.

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* have C++11, you'll need to replace your `bool` array with a class that clears the array in its constructor, since you can only use the default constructor when allocating arrays of objects. This class should contain a `bool*` and have typecast operators to `bool*` and `const bool*` as well as `operator []` overloaded.

Or you can give up on clearing the array at construction and add a `for` loop right after your `someBoolArray = ...` line to do the clearing. Either approach results in the same compiled code.

BTW, the inability to create arrays of objects with constructors other than the default constructor was a language defect addressed by C++11.

Comment: But you can at least call `new bool[N]()`, which will set all the elements to `false`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, that's what I had in mind when I asked about zero-initialization in the comment. Strangely, I can't get boost to accept this. Maybe my version isn't up to date enough.

Answer (score 0):

shared_ptr does not work that way, see e.g., [shared_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used) and [Does C++11 have wrappers for dynamically-allocated arrays like Boost's scoped_array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624146/c11-standard-scoped-array-wrappers).

In answer to your question, a default constructed bool (as you get with `new bool[4711]()`) should have the value false already so you should be OK.

Comment: The question is about `boost::shared_ptr`, which behaves seems to have a specialization for arrays. Also, `new bool[N]` will not set the elements to `false`.

Comment: Default constructor for `bool` is like for other integer types: it does nothing. You may be getting confused by the fact that a function-static or global bool array *is* initialized to 0, but that's a recent thing (I think it carries over from C, actually)  and not required by the standard.