# What is the difference between Boost smart pointers and std smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, std

So, I'd like to use smart pointers instead of raw and almost every topic on SO says about Boost library. But std has such things as `std::auto_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.
Why Boost? What is the difference?

It was a question not about difference of the implementation, but about reasons to use Boost pointers. I suppose, given answer, including date of answering and context, is reasonably useful. It helps to understand how Boost pointers were added to std.

Comment: std::auto_ptr is deprecated btw

Comment: The new smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr` etc. (with the exception of `std::auto_ptr`) in C++11 were modeled after the structures with the same name in Boost.

Comment: Check the dates of those SO items you mention. Several `boost` smart pointers, such as `boost::shared_ptr`, were introduced in the standard only last year (and thus became `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between different flavours of shared\_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086798/differences-between-different-flavours-of-shared-ptr)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Basically Boost did `shared_ptr` first. You may note that many of the new container classes in C++11 were in Boost long ago. I would expect this pattern to continue with the next revisions of the C++ standard, too. Boost supports older C++ compilers that don't talk C++11, which is a big benefit.

Incidentally, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11, which brings in `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` instead, which are both significantly more useful.

Comment: More specifically: Boost is a library playground for authors to explore the design space and validate their libraries with real users. The C++ committee (which features many of such authors) then comes in and standardize what worked.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the following stackoverflow questions:

1. [Difference between boost::shared_ptr and std::shared_ptr from the standard <memory> file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902313/difference-between-boostshared-ptr-and-stdshared-ptr-from-the-standard-memo)
2. [Differences between different flavours of shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086798/differences-between-different-flavours-of-shared-ptr)

Answer (score 4):

Well, `std::shared_ptr` and `boost:shared_ptr` are both reference counting pointers. Instead std::auto_ptr works very differently. The difference between `std::shared_ptr` and `boost:shared_ptr` is very small and mostly historically. Before C++11 there was no `std::shared_ptr` and only `boost:shared_ptr`. When C++11 was designed, they took `boost:shared_ptr` as a model.

All your mentioned smart pointers have in common that they have their own mechanism to make sure that the lifetime management for points is done correctly. `auto_ptr` works so that if you have multiple instances of an `auto_ptr` then only one of them contains a pointer to the real object. Whenever you create an `auto_ptr` from another `auto_ptr`, then the new one will point to the object and the old one to `NULL`. On the other hand with `shared_ptr` there can be multiple `shared_ptr` instances that share the same object, only when the last one goes out of scope, only then the object is deleted..

In C++11 there is a similar pointer type to `std::auto_ptr`, namely `std::unique_ptr`, but there are some important differences, see also
[std::auto_ptr to std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451099/stdauto-ptr-to-stdunique-ptr).

References:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr